# Atom Shortcuts suddenly changed

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

So I'm using Atom on Ubuntu and I've got this problem when Atom shortcuts are suddenly changed from the usual ones. For example my 'cut' is now shift+del instead of ctrl+x.
Atom's shortcut list still says that all of the shortcuts are the same. Ubuntu's shortcut list is the same as well. And all of the shortcuts are woking fine outside of Atom.
With all of that I've got some system problems. If I'm trying to take a screenshot from the Atom it won't do so, but instead locks my cursor everywhere else, changing my cursor to corresponding "screenshot - cut" cursor, but not allowing me to click anywhere except Atom. It also lock's the ability to just select another windows in split-screen mode using my mouse.

Comment: Now windows are broken as well. I can't just click 'minimize', 'close' or just the top of the window itself. I've tryed to reboot, but it stays the same

Comment: I'm experiencing changes in shortcuts on Ubuntu in VS Code as well. Happened after updating kernel and other stuff today.